# Draw 3 verticals Bands on web page

Tags: css, web

I'm kind of new in web developing. I'm trying to draw 3 vertical bands (blue, white, and red) that go all over the top to the bottom of the page but I have no idea how to do it.

```
    <% include partials/header %>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12"> <h3 style="text-align: center">A QUEIJARIA</h3></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <h1 style="text-align: center">alguma frase bacana pra colocar aqui</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6"> <p class="colunas">Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos.</p> </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6"> <p>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos.</p> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="botao">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="quemsomos" >Mais detalhes!</a>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12"> <h3 style="text-align: center">NOSSOS PRODUTOS</h3></div>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                   <img  class="img_queijo">
                   <div class="caption">
                       <h4>Queijos Massa mole afinado</h4>
                   </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                   <img class="img_queijo">
                   <div class="caption">
                       <h4>Queijos Massa semidura</h4>
                   </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="botao">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="produtos" >Nossos Queijos!</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<% include partials/footer %>
```

Comment: you can use `html {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,blue 33.33%, white 33.33%, white 66.66%, red 66.66%);
}` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from comment:

> you can use `html {
>     min-height: 100%;
>     background: linear-gradient(to right,blue 33.33%, white 33.33%, white 66.66%, red 66.66%);
>   }`

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

> The `linear-gradient()` CSS function creates an image consisting of a progressive transition between two or more colors along a straight line. Its result is an object of the `<gradient>` data type, which is a special kind of `<image>`.

---

Demo:

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,blue 33.33%, white 33.33%, white 66.66%, red 66.66%);
}
```

Add some fake contents ? *from https://www.webpagefx.com/web-design/html-ipsum/ .*

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,blue 33.33%, white 33.33%, white 66.66%, red 66.66%);
}
```

```html
<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>

<ol>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>

<blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

<h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ul>

<pre><code>
#header h1 a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
}
</code></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way that i can make those bands only in the left side of the page?

Comment: @PedroSG yes, many ways, from your site structure within another tag element, using background-size and no repeat, updating start/stop value from the gradient itself, .... What have you tried so far that did not work ?

Comment: Hi! I didn't really tried because I didn't know how to do the bands. But I was unable to make the bands appear only in the left, the way you pointed out, the bands appear only if the page is empty.

Comment: @PedroSG You did not really understood my answer. the 3 bands are here shown on the full page even if empty.(this is what you asked for without any more detail) . add content in body, as much you want, the bg of html will still be here. Hints are : background/linear-gradient (1 link provided) / background-size (to reduce it if the start/stop value of linear gradient doesn't  talk to you) . Try something from this answer, so we can help from what you did not understood here or misused. *(if the background desappear once you add something, or you broke the rule or add other bg hidding it :( )*

Comment: @PedroSG added a snippet with fake contents to let you see it goes along with it . Clarify or post some of your code that shows it doesn't work, then we can go further helping ;)

Comment: Got it working, by changind html by body. How can i adjust those bands to only be in the whole left side of the page?

Comment: @PedroSG take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat . You can also look again at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient all the way down to **See Also**  for other gradients functions  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient  ;)

Answer (score -2):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>SimpleByMe</title>
         </head>

         <style type="text/css">

       @media screen and (min-width: 480px) 
       {
        .col-lg-4{
         width: 33.33%;
        float: left;

        }

      .d1
      {
        background-color: green;
      }
      .d2
      {
        background-color: red;
      }
      .d3
      {
        background-color: blue;
      }


       </style>
      <body>

<!-- add data between <div> it will a automatically expand vertically  -->

         <div class ="col-lg-4 d1">1st</div>
        <div class ="col-lg-4 d2"> 2nd</div>
        <div class ="col-lg-4 d3"> 3rd</div>
       </body>
    </html>
```